# when I press the button on screen remains frozen and the progress bar is not displayed until it unlocks

Tags: android

I want to show a progress bar while I copy a file from one location to another (big), but when clicking the select button is pressed directory is not displayed until the operation is over (copy). The button in question is shown above a listview and when clicked want to perform the action and hide. You know it is happening? Thanks in advance.

```
    final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonDir);
    button.getBackground().setAlpha(230);
    button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            progress = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
            progress.setMessage(type);
            progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progress.setIndeterminate(true);
            progress.setCancelable(true);
            progress.setProgress(0);
            progress.setMax(1);
            progress.show();

            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    res = null;
                    while (res == null)
                        res = // return string

                    manejador.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // progress.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            t.start();
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (res.equals("Ok"))
                updatedListView();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling join() that will lock your thread until the other ends.

You must continue with execution and wait a message to be posted async when the task is done.